# Integrating $(x,y,z)$ around the circle centred at $ (0,0,1)$ passing through $(0,0,2)$ and $(0,1,1)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In integrating $(x,y,z)$ around the circle centred at $ (0,0,1)$ passing through $(0,0,2)$ and $(0,1,1)$, the solution I'm seeing starts by saying:

> It's a circle of radius $1$ centered at $(0,0,2)$, lying in the $yz$ plane, described by $x=0$ and $y^2+(z-1)^2=1$

(It then prametrises it and concludes that the answer is $0$). The problem states that the circle is centred at $(0,0,1)$ and the solution starts by saying that it's centred at $(0,0,2)$. So which is it?

How I tried to solve it:

Let $\displaystyle I= \int_{C} (x,y,z)\cdot d\overline{r}$. The circle can be described by $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1$. I parametrised it via: $x= \cos{t},~y=\sin{t},~z=t$ for $t \in [0, 2\pi)$, getting the apparently wrong answer  of $I = \int_0^{2\pi}t  d{t} = 2\pi^2.$

Comment: In either case, neither your parametrisation nor your equation describe a circle, so they are wrong.

Comment: @Miguel Thanks. My equation actually describes a sphere isn't it? Large part of my confusion came from trying to plot a circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It seems the only way is to treat as if the $x$ coordinates in this case isn't there at all, and plot it in $yz$-plane. Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: A circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the intersection of a sphere with a plane *always*, even in your case: do not forget the plane equation $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct equation for the circle is $y^2+(z-1)^2=1$ indeed by the givens the circle can't be centered in (0,0,2) since the distances with $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,1,1)$ are different.

Comment: Makes sense. So their answer is correct (i.e. $I=0$), and they probably mistyped the coordinates for the centre? Thanks.

Comment: @user537566 Yes it seems just a typo in the solution. You are welcome, Bye

Comment: Strictly speaking, you must also include $x=0$ in tthe equation**s** of the circle.